# How can i insert user id and status in mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

My problem is only user id is inserted into database but I want to insert user id, date and radio button value. How can I insert radio button value into the database?
I have 3 employees and I want to insert user id, date and status of a particular user. I have a single submit button and if I press submit then I want to insert all data into database.

Here is my Code:

```
<form>
    <input type="date" name="date" >      
    <table class="display data_tbl">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Date
                </th>
                <th>
                    Employee Name
                </th>
                <th>
                    Status
                </th>

                <th>
                    Action
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php
                error_reporting(0);
                $us=0;
                $at="select * from user_information";
                $atd=mysql_query($at);
                while($data=mysql_fetch_array($atd))
                {
                    $us++;

                    if(isset($_GET['submit']) && $_GET['submit']!='' && $_GET['date']!='')
                    {
                        $a=$_GET['date'];
                        echo $b=date('d-m-Y',strtotime($a));

                        $insert=mysql_query("insert into attendence set user_id='".$data['user_id']."',date='".$b."',status='".$_GET['radio']$us."'");

                    }
                ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $b;?></td>
                    <td align="center"> <?php echo $data['name'];?>
                    </td>
                    <td class="center">
                    </td>
                    <td class="center">

                        <input type="radio" name="radio<?php echo $us;?>" value="Late">Late
                        <input type="radio" name="radio<?php echo $us;?>" value="Absent">Absent
                        <input type="radio" name="radio<?php echo $us;?>" value="Present">Present
                        <input type="radio" name="radio<?php echo $us;?>" value="Halfday">Halfday
                        <input type="radio" name="radio<?php echo $us;?>" value="Leave">Leave
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <?php
                }

            ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Take Attendance">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

firstly there is no need to give radio button name like you give because in radio button only one value can be selected at a time so remove the php value(i think you are using this to make radio button name unique) you are using with radio button name value from radio button name and than try.

Comment: its not an answer. :D

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

My bad for saying you shouldn't use `SET` but here's another way for `INSERT` query:

```
INSERT INTO tablename (column1, column2, etc...) VALUES(value1, value2, etc....)
```

Applying to your code, this:

```
$insert=mysql_query("insert into attendence set user_id='".$data['user_id']."',date='".$b."',status='".$_GET['radio']$us."'");
```

to this:

```
$insert=mysql_query("insert into attendence (user_id, date, status)
values('".$data['user_id']."', '".$b."','".$_GET['radio'].$us."')");
```

And, your radio button should not have a different name so that the user can only select one option.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what's wrong with the SET syntax? I never saw people using it, but it seems perfectly fine to me, especially if one generates queries, and needs something that works for both INSERT and UPDATE.

Comment: and why shouldn't you use the `SET` syntax? its also possible to use this one -> http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html

Comment: if i use---$insert=mysql_query("insert into attendence (user_id, date, status)
values('".$data['user_id']."', '".$b."','".$_GET['radio']$us."')"); it's show error.

Answer (score 0):

You're insert statement has a syntax error, try replacing the following line

```
$insert=mysql_query("insert into attendence set user_id='".$data['user_id']."',date='".$b."',status='".$_GET['radio']$us."'");
```

with the following

```
$insert=mysql_query("insert into attendence(user_id, date, status)  values('".$data['user_id']."','".$b."','".$_GET['radio'].$us."')");
```

Comment: Both syntaxes are perfectly valid in MySQL

Comment: The error that I mentioned was with the $_GET['radio'].$us part, not the insert-into-set syntax.

Answer (score 0):

There are many problem in your posted script

- firstly as cyber_rookie mentioned, there is query syntax error in
  data insert
- secondly you have added submit button code inside `while` loop, which
  is wrong, as `while` you are using for preparing display data and
  submit code should be executed on submit button click

I have tried to make bit correct, please find code here https://jsfiddle.net/h5e5Lxnm/ you can check and modify it according to your requirement.

This code will give you all selected data (including date, radio vlaues and all)